# sign and verify using openssl library functions instead of command line utilities

Tags: c, openssl

I am currently framing the openssl commands as a string and using linux system call `int system(const char *command);` for signing and verifying certain files.

For generating sha i use below command.

```
openssl dgst -sha256   > test_sha256.txt
```

After generating `test_sha256.txt`, i will sign this with my CA , which gives me `signature.p7s`, from which i extract CRLs(`asn1parse -inform DER` and `dd` ) and combining CRLs with my root CA, then i verify using below command.

```
openssl cms -verify -inform DER -in signature.p7s -binary -content test_sha256.txt -CAfile combined_CA.pem -purpose any -signer signer_file.crt
```

How can we achieve the same thing using the `openssl` library calls? Do we have separate `openssl` functions to achieve sign & verify.

Comment: Have you seen the OpenSSL wiki page [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying)?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek, This is the first time got into OpenSSL, will have a look at it and revert if have any doubts, thanks